# Filter Search To Posts with a Specific Template

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way using Wordpress to modify the native search function, so that only posts of a specific page template are show. For example:

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');

```
function searchfilter($query) {

    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_template','a-template-name'); // Pseudocode
    }

    return $query;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function searchfilter($query) {

if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('meta_key','_wp_page_template');
    $query->set('meta_value', 'page-some-template.php'); //Change filename to yours
}

return $query;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, jack- it's great to be here!